# Attach XML object to REST POST in asp.net REST starter kit

Tags: asp.net, xml, rest, httpclient

I'm using the REST starter kit in asp.net for the first time and having a bit of trouble.

I've created some XML...

```
String newOrganizationStrin = "<somexml></somexml>";
XmlDocument newOrganizationXml = new XmlDocument();
newOrganizationXml.LoadXml(newOrganizationString);
```

Then I create an httpClient...

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient("https://companyname.capsulecrm.com/api/");
http.TransportSettings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("APIKEY", "PASSWORD");
```

Now I need to use http.POST() to post the xml to the correct URL. The overloaded method I need I think is (string url, httpContent body). So I guess the missing piece of the puzzle is how to convert the xml to an httpContent, which I can't seem to instantiate.

Any ideas?

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really starting with a string, the easiest way is

```
var content = HttpContent.Create("<somexml></somexml>","application/xml");
```

The other way is to use XElement

```
var content = HttpContentExtensions.Create(XElement.Parse("<somexml></somexml>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found the answer -

```
HttpContent content = HttpContentExtensions.CreateXmlSerializable(newOrganizationXml);
```